# Auto-Complete TextInput - Match Beginning of String Only

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

My question concerns the following tutorial I've been working through:

[Building a Flex Type-Ahead Text Input](http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-a-flex-type-ahead-text-input)

I was successful in enabling a search of available terms using the characters entered in the input, but only irrespective of the location of the characters in the terms.  However, I am wondering how one might have the characters match only the beginning of the terms.

For example, suppose I enter the string "*app*" into the text input.  How can I get only "*apple*" and not, for instance, "*pineapple*" to appear as an option?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function filterSelection(item:Object):Boolean{
 if (String(item).indexOf(fruit.text)==0){
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}
```